# Can't import svg with icons in Android Studio

Tags: android, svg, vector, import

I'm trying to import SVG file to Android Studio. The icons present in the SVG file are not being shown while importing. They are not visible even after importing is done. There are some warnings are which I have no idea of:

```
In smart_search.svg:
ERROR @ line 19:<filter> is not supported
ERROR @ line 20:<feFlood> is not supported
```

This is the snap of the actual SVG file.

[image]

This is the snap after importing to Android Studio

[image]

The svg code is very large.

After shortening I posted it here.

[smart_search.svg](https://textuploader.com/150p6)

Answer (score 0):

I've saved the image and it seems distorted:

[image: distorted svg image]

Have you tried some third party converters? I have used these two in the past:
https://shapeshifter.design/

http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

I also recommend to break the icons, texts and the background in smaller components and build a custom component using ConstraintLayout.